# Increase click count by user defined value

Tags: android

I'm new to Android so sorry if the question is easy to answer.

I have made click count app which works with touch instead of a button, but with that, I want to implement a number box on which user can enter the value and shows that provided number and add that same given value.

for example: if the value entered is 3, then next value would be 6-9-12.. and so on.

here is my java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    touchCountText = findViewById(R.id.touchCountText);
}

public void touchFunc (View v){
    tCount++;
    touchCountText.setText(""+tCount);
    vibrator.vibrate(40);
}
public void reset (View v){
    tCount = 0;
    touchCountText.setText(""+tCount);
    vibrator.vibrate(100);
}
```

Comment: It is a simple thing. I think you better learn some basics first. Checkout these course on Udacity.com if you like https://in.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837

Comment: to implement a number box on which user can enter the value - you OK to use EditText ? That is simplest option available to accept input that I am aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `tCount` by itself by adding another variable that accumulates for each click.

```
int accCount = 0;
int tCount = 3; // Just to test it like in your example

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    touchCountText = findViewById(R.id.touchCountText);
}

public void touchFunc (View v){
    accCount = accCount + tCount;
    touchCountText.setText(""+accCount);
    vibrator.vibrate(40);
}

public void reset (View v){
    accCount = 0;
    touchCountText.setText(""+accCount);
    vibrator.vibrate(100);
}
```

Getting the input of the user is another task. Study about `EditText` where you can use `getText()` to get the defined value from the user then assign it to your `tCount` variable.

Comment: hello, this somehow worked but not as it should ... when i click it counts in multiple .. for example 1-8-45-78 without entering any value  | i tried putting touchCountText.setText(""+tcount+accCount), but still it counts as before,
i really appriciate your help.

Comment: What did you set as the value of `tCount`? Try initializing it first with 3 like in your example `int tCount = 3;`  because you've said that you haven't entered any value.

Comment: Int tCount = 0;

Comment: How are you changing the value of tCount? I don't understand how it could be 1-8-45-78 when the tCount is 0.

Comment: int tCount = 0;
    int accCount = 0;public void touchFunc (View v){
        tCount++;
        accCount = accCount + tCount;
        touchCountText.setText(""+accCount);
        touchCountText.setText(""+tCount);
        vibrator.vibrate(40);
    }       what am i doing wrong? please guide me

Comment: it worked! thank you!!

one more this how can i link tCount  to edit text i so i can give the number and it doubles on click?

Comment: inPut = inPut.getText().toString();
        int tCount = Integer.valueOf(inPut);      it is giving me error on getText().... what do i search on google .. sorry for being dumb

Comment: Sorry if I've mistaken TextView for EditText previously. You should be using getText() on an EditText. Create an EditText first.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_edittext_control.htmroid.com/ui/edittext